# Count cases in xpath where date is in last six months

Tags: xml, date, xpath, count, compare

I have had a search but struggling to find an answer that I understand/can use. Basically, I need to use an xpath which compares a date to today in certain circumstances.

The xml block I'm interrogating contains several account records, an excerpt example of one block below with relevant data:

```
<acc>
  <default>
     <defdate>2017-07-01</defdate>
     <defsatdate>2017-09-01</defsatdate>
  </default>    
</acc>
```

I need to count how many accounts have a defdate within the last six months of today, but where the account has not been satisfied. That is where defdate is present and within the last six months, and defsatdate is NOT present. (Note if the account hasn't entered default, the  section will not be present at all).

Note that this xpath will be running in a live environment so the date part needs to be dynamic and work out what today is, rather than me being able to fix that in the xpath.

So in the above example the account defaulted within the last six months but was also satisfied. As such it wouldn't enter my count.

I've had a look at the translate function etc but am still quite a newbie so struggling a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
count(//acc[not(.//defsatdate) and 
            translate(.//defdate, '-','') <= '20171031' and
            translate(.//defdate, '-','') >= '20170331'])
```

(Line breaks is added for readability)

Necessary explanations

```
//acc[not(.//defsatdate)      - find `acc` without `defsatdate`
translate(.//defdate, '-','') - remove dash from the string
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, hopefully this helps with part of the query, I'm hoping to somehow do the date comparison dynamically as the xpath will be running in an online environment (i.e. I'd want to say <= today, and >= today-6 months) where the system somehow looks at the system date at the time the xpath is run? Would that be dependent on the system the search will be running in, or is there an xpath function for today()?

Comment: At least, xpath 1.0 can't do so. I use a trick to convert date to integer, ordered as date. You should set dates using program language. It is not difficult